# Increase speed to 9600-19200 in optical communication circuit

Tags: transistors, communication, photodiode, optical

The circuit in the picture is the optical communication circuit of the RX. Currently, its maximum speed of communication is 2400. I want to increase the speed to 9600-19200. I have lowered the resistance, but it hasn't improved yet. Do I need to calculate anything else?

[image: optical communication circuit of the RX]

---

I am using an optical probe as a transmitter, specifically the Hichi TTL-IR model. I don't have much information about the Tx probe, but I have set the distance between the Tx and Rx to be 10 cm.

The picture below shows the bit rate of 2400 for the Hichi TTL-IR.

[image]

---

Below is the RX bit rate, which should be within the range of 416 μs.
[image]

Comment: Which resistance you changed? How do you know it is the correct resistanve to change?

Comment: Why would you change something in the Rx (receiver) circuit to change the speed? I would think you would need to increase the Tx (transmitter) speed instead.

Comment: To expand on what @Rodo is getting at, are you sure the receiver is the bottleneck, and how did you determine that?  There are lots of reasons that the communication speed could be limited that could have nothing to do with the receiver circuit shown.  (Though I wouldn't expect the circuit shown to have high bandwidth.)

Comment: I found that the bit rate is not aligned. With a baud rate of 2400, the result at the receiver (Rx) is 52us, which should be acceptable at 416 μs.

Comment: @sso - Hi, Please immediately stop adding new information by writing *answers*. That is against the rules here. It seems that you are treating the site like a forum. However Stack Exchange (SE) his different rules & etiquette. Please stop & read the [tour] & [help], and especially learn about the SE approach of having Q&A in different places, and the concept of *editing the question* to add new information. Since you asked the question, please do not use the box at the bottom of the page labeled "Your Answer" *unless* you have solved your own problem and are adding the *full & final* solution.

Comment: so the problem is tha the transmitter/receiver makes the pulses slightly narrower?

Comment: Comparing the two screen shots, **Hichi TTL-IR** appears to have a *logic-low* time span equal to its *logic-high* time span. But **RX bit-rate** screen shot looks unequal (logic-low span is longer than logic-high). If distance between RX and TX is changed, observe the received pulse widths, and see if their high/low times vary.